# Rails app with remote database - should I duplicate in my app or connect remotely

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm building a new rails app for a client. They already have a separate rails app that manages users (with all the standard Devise fields) and don't want to have to maintain users in both apps, which makes total sense.

I'm able to connect to their remote database using database.yml for the connection details and establish_connection: in my User model. It works, although is a bit slow (going over the public internet). I'm concerned that relying on this remote database for something that is queried A LOT will seriously slow down my app. I also won't be able to do joins with the remote database.

My thought is to duplicate the user table in my app and have a cron job that runs once every few hours (or even more frequently) that keeps my table in sync with the "master".

Is there any reason not to do that? Is it a terrible idea from a design perspective?

I should mention that my DB is postgres and the remote DB is mysql. I also started reading up on the DbCharmer gem (http://dbcharmer.net/) but I don't fully understand it yet.

--Edit:--

I should also mention that I will need to read other tables from the remote DB, not just the users table.

Comment: I would setup something like oauth at the side of the existing db -> because the slowdown of your db connection will increase with time.

Comment: I was thinking about that but there are some other tables I need to access from the remote DB. I'll update my question to include that.

Comment: You can also use multiple dbs in rails, so that some models use the remote db and others the local one. Another approach could be, setup a master-slave db system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend *caching* their DB locally, so when you look up a remote record you record it locally (if it existed remotely) or you record a *negative result* locally if it didn't exist remotely - you cache a record of the remote record's absence. Remember to cache negative results for less time than positive results.

You can then look at your local cache and see if there's a fresh-enough result to return and only query the remote if the locally cached result is stale or there isn't a locally cached result.

This is how I'd do it personally; I'd cache rather than copy and sync. You can certainly combine the two approaches by pre-fetching commonly fetched things into the cache on a regular basis, though.

There's no need to use Pg for the local cache, you can just as easily use redis/memcached/whatever (and I'm a Pg dev, so I'm not exactly biased in favour of Redis).

Comment: Thanks Craig! this sounds like the way to go. Do you think using low level caching in rails to store the remote DB results is a good idea?

Comment: @user1202726 I don't really use Rails, so I couldn't comment on that. Maybe post a new question?

Comment: Ok, I will. Thanks for the suggestions